Observing computed properties of derived class
I find myself using a derived class that I mark with the @Observable macro. For every computed property of the base class I need to go through the following for the observability for this property to work:
class Base {
  var size: CGSize { get set }
}

@Observable class Derived : Base {
  override var size: CGSize {
    set {
      withMutation(keyPath: \.size) {
        super.size = newValue
      }
    }
    get {
      access(keyPath: \.size)
      return super.size
    }
  }
}

The pattern is expected but really, I have to do all this typing for every one of the dozen or whatever properties?
Am I doing this wrong?  Is there a better/cleverer/more efficient way, like a one-liner per property?  I do not control the base class (e.g., SKScene from SpriteKit).
I was thinking of trying a macro for that but honestly, I've never written one so not sure if it's worth investing the time and effort at this point.  But if anyone knows of a different approach here that is better, please show it.

I think there is no other choice than macros. The simplest solution is to just write an accessor macro like this:
// declaration
@attached(accessor, names: named(set), named(get))
public macro TrackSuper() = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "TrackSuper")

// implementation
enum TrackSuper: AccessorMacro {
    static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax, providingAccessorsOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol, in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [AccessorDeclSyntax] {
        guard let name = declaration.as(VariableDeclSyntax.self)?.bindings.first?.pattern
            .as(IdentifierPatternSyntax.self)?.identifier else {
            return []
        }
        return [
        """
        get {
            access(keyPath: \\.\(name))
            return super.\(name)
        }
        """,
        """
        set {
            withMutation(keyPath: \\.\(name)) {
                super.\(name) = newValue
            }
        }
        """
        ]
    }
}

@main
struct MyMacroPlugin: CompilerPlugin {
    let providingMacros: [Macro.Type] = [
        TrackSuper.self
    ]
}

Usage:
class Foo {
    var size: Int = 0
}

@Observable
class Bar: Foo {
    // the order here is important - @TrackSuper must go first
    // this is perhaps due to a implementation detail of @Observable
    @TrackSuper
    @ObservationIgnored
    override var size: Int
}


A second design is a member macro, automatically generating overrides of the properties. The user can specify the properties that they want to override when applying the macro.
// declaration
@attached(member, names: arbitrary)
public macro TrackSuper<Root: AnyObject, each T>(_ properties: repeat (KeyPath<Root, each T>, (each T).Type)) = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "TrackSuper")

// implementation
enum TrackSuper: MemberMacro {
    
    private struct PropertyNameAndType {
        let name: TokenSyntax
        let type: TokenSyntax
    }
    
    static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax, providingMembersOf declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax, in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        guard let tupleExprs = node.arguments?.as(LabeledExprListSyntax.self)?.compactMap({ $0.expression.as(TupleExprSyntax.self) })
        else {
            return []
        }
        let namesAndTypes = tupleExprs.compactMap(tupleExpressionToNameAndType)
        return namesAndTypes.map {
            """
            override var \($0.name): \($0.type) {
                get {
                    access(keyPath: \\.\($0.name))
                    return super.\($0.name)
                }
                set {
                    withMutation(keyPath: \\.\($0.name)) {
                        super.\($0.name) = newValue
                    }
                }
            }
            """
        }
    }
    
    private static func tupleExpressionToNameAndType(_ expr: TupleExprSyntax) -> PropertyNameAndType? {
        guard let keyPath = expr.elements.first?.expression.as(KeyPathExprSyntax.self),
              case let .property(component) = keyPath.components.first?.component,
              let type = expr.elements.dropFirst().first?.expression.as(MemberAccessExprSyntax.self)?.base,
              let typeToken = type.as(DeclReferenceExprSyntax.self)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        return PropertyNameAndType(name: component.declName.baseName, type: typeToken.baseName)
    }
}

@main
struct MyMacroPlugin: CompilerPlugin {
    let providingMacros: [Macro.Type] = [
        TrackSuper.self,
    ]
}

Usage:
class Foo {
    var size = 0
    var somethingElse = ""
}

// in this case the order doesn't matter
@TrackSuper(
    (\Foo.size, Int.self), 
    (\.somethingElse, String.self) 
    /* and so on... */
)
@Observable
class Bar: Foo {
    // the class body can be left empty
}

Note that you also need to specify the types of the properties, otherwise the macro doesn't know the type of the property to generate.

Thanks for the detailed response and example, I went with the accessor macro and it works great! Need to read up on macros so I can start writing my own.
